# AngularJS directive dynamic templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make directive with differtent templates based on scope value.

This is what i done so far which i don't know why doesn't work http://jsbin.com/mibeyotu/1/edit

HTML element:

```
<data-type content-attr="test1"></data-type>
```

Directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('dataType', function ($compile) {

    var testTemplate1 = '<h1>Test1</h1>';
    var testTemplate2 = '<h1>Test2</h1>';
    var testTemplate3 = '<h1>Test3</h1>';

    var getTemplate = function(contentType){

        var template = '';

        switch(contentType){
            case 'test1':
                template = testTemplate1;
                break;
            case 'test2':
                template = testTemplate2;
                break;
            case 'test3':
                template = testTemplate3;
                break;
        }

        return template;
    }; 

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.html(getTemplate(scope.content)).show();
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            content:'='
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/ :) it seems that many of us need/like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) You are passing content as attribute in your html. Try this:

```
element.html(getTemplate(attrs.content)).show();
```

instead of:

```
element.html(getTemplate(scope.content)).show();
```

2) data part of directive is getting compiled so you should use something else. Instead of data-type, e.g. datan-type.

Here is the link:

http://jsbin.com/mibeyotu/6/edit

Comment: Just one question, if i'm doing ng-repeat, for example: ng-repeat="p in people" i can't get value like this: content="p.name". Because this  directive is inside ng-repeat cycle.

Comment: I'm getting errors when 'show' is called at the end. Work properly without it. Not sure if it's a legacy thing or what.

Comment: @Slaven Tomac I am trying to add form elements dynamically. But when adding items with ng-repeat and ng-options dynamically it does not show the repeat items. Just the static HTML. Here is what I mean to say. http://plnkr.co/edit/JOzTWB6tuyilCJ8Rj37Q Any issues with the code or can ng-repeat be also compiled in the template.

Answer (score 119):

You can set the `template` property of your directive definition object to a function that will return your dynamic template:

```
restrict: "E",
replace: true,
template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
    return getTemplate(tAttrs.content);
}
```

Notice that you don't have access to scope at this point, but you can access the attributes through `tAttrs`.

Now your template is being determined before the compile phase, and you don't need to manually compile it.

Comment: Please note that templateUrl can also be a function

Comment: the tAttrs.content doesnt return the actual value of the content, just the hmtl template value.

Answer (score 22):

You can also do it very straightforward like this:

```
appDirectives.directive('contextualMenu', function($state) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: function(){
        var tpl = $state.current.name;
        return '/app/templates/contextual-menu/'+tpl+'.html';
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: How would you pass `$state` to the directive?

Comment: Best answer if you're looking for simple method to control`template` based on the route.

Comment: @tftd like this `(function(angular){
 angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router'])
 .directive('myDirective', ['$state', function($state){
  return {
   templateUrl: 'tpl.html'
  };
 }]);
})(window.angular);`

Comment: when `templateUrl` is specified like a function that function receives two arguments, the first is the element and the second is the scope.  So to get hold of the isolated scope is easier to use the one from the callback : `{templateUrl : function($el, $scope) { return '..'+$scope.name+'..'}}`

Comment: @Tiberiu C. The second argument is not the $scope, but the attributes.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to load your template based on `$scope` variables you can do it using `ng-include`:

```js
.directive('profile', function() {
  return {
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>',
    scope: {
      user: '=data'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope) {
      //function used on the ng-include to resolve the template
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
        //basic handling
        if ($scope.user.type == 'twitter') {
          return 'twitter.tpl.html';
        }
        if ($scope.user.type == 'facebook') {
          return 'facebook.tpl.html';
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Reference: https://coderwall.com/p/onjxng/angular-directives-using-a-dynamic-template

Comment: hi,
When i implemented the same code as yours i am getting error as 
angular.js:13708 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: <ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/> (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
Could you please help me out with this

Comment: Could you provide directive controller code? My guess is that directive's scope doesn't have the `getTemplateUrl` function and browser tries to load `undefined` template.

Comment: This doesn't work if your directive is using `transclude`, but nice approach anyway ;)