# Angular dynamic template with controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a template with a controller using  a directive:

```
<div directOne>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
a.directive("direct-one", function ($templateRequest, $compile, $controller) {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $templateRequest("template.html").then(function (html) {
            var $scope = scope.$new();
            $controller('oneController', {$scope, $scope});
            var template = angular.element(html);
            $(elem).append(template);
            template = $compile(template)(scope);
        });
    }
  };
});
```

template:

```
<span ng-bind="test"></span>
<div ng-controler="oneController">
</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('oneController', function () {
   $scope.test = '123456';
}
```

My problem that is the test value is not shown.

I have seen some working samples of what I am doing. My real code is more complex.

Hope, someone can help me.

Thanks

Update 1
My code should look like this then:

```
<div  style="width:90%;height:100%">
     <div ng-controler="oneController" directOne>        
</div>
```

And that code is a part of another template with its own controller. So, unless I have $scope.test on the **parent controller** the data is not shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS directive dynamic templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065165/angularjs-directive-dynamic-templates)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the Controller div around anything that accesses your controller. So it should be:

```
 <div ng-controler="oneController">
     <span ng-bind="test"></span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do exactly opposite of what you are currently doing.

While defining directive you should name it as `directOne` & then use that directive with `-` separated value instead of Upper case letter like `direct-one`.

`ng-bind="test"` value haven't evaluated because you attached controller to directive DOM.

For fixing your issue, you need to compile your new `template.html` element with `$controller('oneController', {$scope, $scope});` scope, then will be able to evaluate the value of `test` variable.

Otherwise you could easily fix this by using directive `controller` option.

**Markup**

```
<div direct-one></div>
```

**Directive**

```
a.directive("directOne", function ($templateRequest, $compile, $controller) {
return {
    //controller: 'oneController',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        $templateRequest("template.html").then(function (html) {
            var $scope = scope.$new();
            //stored oneController scope in variable
            var controllerScope = $controller('oneController', {$scope, $scope});
            var template = angular.element(html);
            $(elem).append(template);
            template = $compile(template)(controllerScope); //compiled with oneController scope
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: @Mark do look at updated answer..that most probably help you.. Thanks :)