# AngularJS: Change TemplateUrl for Directive on click

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I am working on Google Maps with Angular, I have created a few markers on the Map with a `$http` call. When the user clicks on a particular Marker, I am showing some details about the Location. I have achieved this in the following way.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('someController', [...some services , function(...){
    //Handling Click on the Map Marker and Drawing Them
    var drawMarkers = function(){
       angular.forEach($scope.items, function(val, key){
            $scope.markers[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: val.lat_lng[0], lng: val.lat_lng[1]},
                map: $scope.map,
            }).addListener('click', function(){ 
                $scope.showDetails(val);
            });
        });  
    }

    //Function to show the Details
    $scope.showRestaurantDetails = function(item){
        $scope.itemInOverlay = item;        
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}]);
```

**HTML(View)**

```
<div class="item-details">
     ....

     <item-offers offer-count="2" item-id="{{itemInOverlay.item_id}}" item-handle="{{item.item_handle}}">
    </item-offers>

     ....
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        itemId: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
        scope.$watch(scope.itemId, function(){
            console.log('changed');
        });

        scope.getTemplateUrl = function(el, attrs){
            if(attrs.offerCount <= 2 && !utilityServices.isMobile())
                var url = '/restaurant/'+attrs.itemHandle+'/'+attrs.itemId+'/partials/offer/single';
            else
                var url = '/restaurant/'+attrs.itemHandle+'/'+attrs.itemId+'/partials/offer/multiple';

            return url;
        };
    },
    templateUrl: getTemplateUrl()
};
```

So now the issue it, whenever the user clicks on the Marker, the `item-handle` and `item-id` change. And I want to load partials with different information on this change.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS directive dynamic templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065165/angularjs-directive-dynamic-templates)

Comment: The solutions to that particular question do not address the problem of changing the template on a click event.